# Using global enum members in a different source file

Tags: c, enums

So I have a global enum defined inside `main.c` which I want to use in a different source file, but can't seem to do so.

```
// main.c
typedef enum BUTTON_STATUS{
    BUTTON_PRESSED,
    BUTTON_NOT_PRESSED
} BUTTON;

// it.c
extern enum BUTTON_STATUS buttonStatus;

void foo() {
   uint8_t button = BUTTON_PRESSED;   //  BUTTON_PRESSED undeclared
}
```

Comment: you can take away BUTTON_STATUS in the very first line and name the enum below instead of "BUTTON"; and it.c can not know the declaration because you wrote it in main.c. You have a much easier life when you use header files `.h` for such declarations and include them in the c files you need them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `BUTTON_PRESSED` undeclared error because `it.c` does not know about it. Move the `enum` to a header file, say `myheader.h`:

```
// myheader.h
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H

typedef enum BUTTON_STATUS{
    BUTTON_PRESSED,
    BUTTON_NOT_PRESSED
} BUTTON;

#endif
```

Include this header in both the files `main.c` and `it.c`.
`main.c` file:

```
// main.c
#include <myheader.h>

BUTTON buttonStatus;

int main(void) {
    ....
    ....
}
```

`it.c` file:

```
// it.c
#include <myheader.h>

extern BUTTON buttonStatus;

void foo(void) {
    buttonStatus = BUTTON_PRESSED;
    ....
    ....
}
```